# Fourier Transform Of male and female voice

Tags: matlab, signals, fft

I'm doing fourier transform using matlab R2014a, first I have read two audio files of femal and male, then I initialized the magnitude and phase for each. A Task in my report requires to Mix female speech amplitude with phase spectrum of the other signal-male phase-, or viceversa, So I wrote a code and I keep getting this error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
out1 = Mag_Male*exp(1i*Phase_Fem);
```

And even using.*

```
Error in Untitled9 (line 183)
out1 = Mag_Male.*exp(1i*Phase_Fem);
```

or .* in both operators

**The full error**

```
>> Untitled9
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in Untitled9 (line 183)
out1 = Mag_Male.*(exp(1i.*Phase_Fem));
```

**Output of m and f size using size function**

***code:***

```
maleAudio_row = size(m);
femaleAudio_row = size(f);
display(maleAudio_row);
display(femaleAudio_row);
```

***Output:***

maleAudio_row =

```
  119855           2
```

femaleAudio_row =

```
  119070           1
```

although my other colleagues worked fine with them :(

This is my Code:

```
Fs = 11025;
Ts = 1/Fs;
t = 0:Ts:0.1;
[m, Fs]=audioread('hamid1.wav');
[f, Fs]=audioread('myvoice.wav');
player = audioplayer(m,Fs);
player2 = audioplayer(f,Fs);
%play(player2);
%---- Frquency Domain Sampling-----%
Fem = fft(f);
Phase_Fem = angle(Fem);
Mag_Fem = abs(Fem);
%-----------------------------------%
Male = fft(m);
Mag_Male = abs(Male);
Phase_Male = angle(Male);
%-----------------------------------%
out1 = Mag_Male*exp(1i*Phase_Fem); % this step for putting female phase on male  mag.
out2 = ifft(out1); % this step is convert the previus step to time domain so i can     
%play the audio
Nx = length(out2);
F0 = 1/(Ts*Nx2);
result = audioplayer(out2); 
play(result);
```

Comment: You probably need to use `.*` not just `*`

Comment: Probably, also a good idea to check the .wav files have the same number of channels (i.e. size(m,2) and size(f,2) are the same)

Comment: @nkjt I did it like this .* but still give me the same error.

Comment: @Kostya how I can check the number of channels could you tell me please?

Comment: What error did you get? Matlab error messages are usually very useful, so show us the full message. I think the error will probably be cause `Mag_Male` and `Phase_Fem` are different sizes, because the length of each `.wav` file may be different

Comment: @AMH9 do `size(Male)` and `size(Fem)`. They will be different, and yo will have to think how to resolve that.

Comment: @David I added the full error in my post above, and also I have cut one of the audio to make both the same length- they are 00:00:02 both with type wav

Comment: @AMH9 Could you post outputs of size(m) and size(f)?

Comment: @Kostya I edited the post and added the output you can check it now, it gives 2 for size(m) i think this means 2 rows, and 1 for size(f).

Comment: @AMH9 No, it means you have 119855 rows and 2 columns in m file, and 119070 rows and 1 column in f. Just convert 2 channels to 1, and follow other suggestions by James and David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'hamid1.wav' is two-channel wav file whereas 'myvoice.wav' is one-channel wav. As mentioned in Matlab manual (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html)

> Audio data in the file, returned as an m-by-n matrix, where m is the number of audio samples read and n is the number of audio channels in the file.

Just convert m to one channel as m = 0.5*(m(:,1)+m(:,2)), adjust other dimension and use .* product (as people suggested in the comments).

```
clear all; 
m = randn(1000,2); %dummy signal
f = randn(999,1); %dummy signal
N = min(size(m,1),size(f,1));

Male = fft(0.5*(m(1:N,1)+m(1:N,2)));
Fem = fft(f(1:N,1));

Mag_Male = abs(Male);
Phase_Male = angle(Male);

Phase_Fem = angle(Fem);
Mag_Fem = abs(Fem);

out1 = Mag_Male.*exp(1i*Phase_Fem);
```

Comment: Ok so I have fixed number of coulmns of m to be 1, but gave me the same error, then I realized that the problem not only with coulmns number but also with rows, as you mentioned above m hase 119855 rows and 1 coulmns - after fixing - and f has 119070 rows and 1 coulmns, but when i tried different audio files for m and f that both has exactly the same rows and coulmns number - I tried 55125 rows and 1 coulmn- it worked.

Comment: Exactly. You can use the original files as well after making m and f  dimensions equal.  One sec, will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use a * it will try and do matrix multiplication. What you probably want to use is an element by element operator, which is a . before the *. This will multiply the first element in the vector with the first element in the other vector, the second with the second, etc. etc.

```
out1 = Mag_Male.*exp(1i*Phase_Fem);
```

This assumes that the result from your FFT is the same length. This will be the case if the original samples are the same length.

Comment: I understand thank you, but seems this is not the issue also.